# get the last column before null columns sql

Tags: sql, sql-server

How can I retrieve the last non-null value in a row of a table in DB? 
Assuming values are non-nulls and then all nulls.

For example, assume there are 5 columns in a table (A B C D E).  Here is a sample row data:

```
A B C    D    E
1 2 NULL NULL NULL
1 2 3    NULL NULL
```

I need to get for 1st row - value 2, for second row - value 3. Rows are processed in a cursor.

Thank you

Comment: *Rows are processed in a cursor.* what do you meant by this ? How this data got generated ?

Comment: Data is imported from Excel file into a table . In order to process the data correctly (insert data into different tables) I need to call a stored procedure for each row of the table - in order to do so I am using cursor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use `coalesce()`:

```
select coalesce(e, d, c, b, a) as last_not_null
from t;
```

Answer (score 1):

Sql do have a inbuilt function `COALESCE` for non-null expression in the list.
The `COALESCE()` function returns the first non-null expression in a list.